204 No Content fot Get(session)
i need a lite help!
I have deploy now my backend(ASP.NET) and frontend(React) and everythink good.
Alla GET, POST, DELET ... reques work good when i call to API.
BUT !!!
The Get(Session) request no work, i get only "204 No Content", The Post(Session) work good OK200.
I test tools like a Postman to check !, when i send a Get(Session) request i get "204 No Content", BUT if i send first Post(Session) reques then i get the Get(Session) request work good OK200, and ID:0.
So what i have to do now !!
HERE is my App.jsx file

import "./sass/main.scss";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import StickyFooter from './components/StickyFooter/StickyFooter';
import MainMenu from '@/components/MainMenu/MainMenu.jsx';
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { get, post } from './ApiConnection.jsx';

export default function App() {

    const [globals, setGlobals] = useState({
        user: [],
        servics: []
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                await post('sessions');
                const user = await get('sessions');
                const servics = await get('servics');
                await setGlobals({ user, servics });
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data: ', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);

    return <>
        <header>
            <MainMenu user={globals.user} />
        </header>
        <main className="h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-content-center mt-3">
            <Outlet context={globals} />
        </main>
        <StickyFooter />

    </>;
}


My ApiConnection.jsx file
const BASE_URL = 'https://backendURL.com';

export async function get(route, method = 'GET') {
    return await (
        await fetch(BASE_URL + '/api/' + route, { method }))
        .json()
        .catch(e => ({ error: e + '' }));
};

export async function post(route, body, method = 'POST') {
    return await (await fetch(BASE_URL + '/api/' + route, {
        method,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    })).json().catch(e => ({ error: e }));
};



configuring from Program.cs
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".MySessionName.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});



/// --------------



app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSession();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


......................
